How to Combine NextAuth(v5) and Next-Intl Middleware in Next.js(app route)
I'm working on a Next.js application that uses NextAuth(v5) for authentication and Next-Intl for internationalization. I need to combine these functionalities seamlessly. Here's what I've tried so far:
Current Middleware:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "src/app/auth.config";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)"],
};

Previous Approach (Not Applicable in NextAuth v5):
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'; // Deprecated in NextAuth v5

// ... (middleware logic using withAuth, not applicable in v5)

https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#example-auth-js
Explanation:

NextAuth v5 no longer uses the withAuth middleware directly. This approach won't work with the current version.


Does this answer your question? https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/issues/596

This works:
middleware.js
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const internationalizationMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "de"],
  defaultLocale: "de",
});

export async function middleware(request) {
  let response = NextResponse.next();

  // Exclude specific paths from further processing
  if (
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api") &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next") &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.includes(".")
  ) {
    return internationalizationMiddleware(request);
  }
  // Return the response object directly
  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)"],
};

auth.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import github from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut, update } = NextAuth(() => {
  return {
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    debug: false,
    basePath: "/api/auth",
    providers: [github]
  };
});


I followed next-intl' documentation and adapted it to version 5 of next-auth.
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { auth } from "./auth";
import { routing } from "./i18n/routing";

const  locales = ["en", "pt"];

const publicPages = ["/auth"]; // your public routes
const handleI18nRouting = createMiddleware(routing);

const authMiddleware = auth((req) => {
  return handleI18nRouting(req);
});

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const publicPathnameRegex = RegExp(
    `^(/(${locales.join("|")}))?(${publicPages
      .flatMap((p) => (p === "/" ? ["", "/"] : p))
      .join("|")})/?$`,
    "i"
  );
  const isPublicPage = publicPathnameRegex.test(req.nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isPublicPage) return handleI18nRouting(req);
  else return (authMiddleware as any)(req);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
};

I had some difficulties modifying the next-auth middleware a lot, but this way, returning the intl middleware worked correctly.
I recommend you do the authorization part directly in the next-auth authorized callback
// auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
 
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [your-credentials],
  callbacks: {
        authorized: ({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) => {
          const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
          const isOnProtectRoute = nextUrl.pathname.includes("/protect"); // just a example
          if (isOnProtectRoute ) {
            if (isLoggedIn) return true;
            return Response.redirect(new URL("/login", nextUrl));
          } else if (isLoggedIn) {
            return Response.redirect(new URL("/protect", nextUrl));
          }
          return true;
        },
      }
})

